# Extending the Set datatype in swift

Tags: ios, swift, set

I am a swift newbie. I have created a new method in the Set data structure for my code. This method inserts into set only if the value is not equal to a particular number.

```
extension Set {
    mutating func addExcludingCurrent(value: Int, currIndex: Int) {
        if value == currIndex {
            return
        } else {
            self.insert(value) // Error
        }
    }
}
```

`Cannot invoke 'insert' with an argument list of type '(Int)'` . How do I resolve it. Or else is there a better way to do this task ??

Comment: Don't use an extension, this is not a common functionality that needs to be added to `Set`. Just use a method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `Set` is a `struct` whose `AssociatedType` is defined as `Element`. So you can extend it by inserting Elements, and not integers:

```
extension Set {
  mutating func addExcludingCurrent(value: Element, currIndex: Element) {
    if value == currIndex {
      return
    } else {
      self.insert(value)
    }
  }
}

var a = Set<Int>();
a.insert(3)
a.addExcludingCurrent(5,currIndex: 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
extension Set {
    mutating func addExcludingCurrent(value: Element, currIndex: SetIndex<Element>) {
        if value == currIndex {
            return
        } else {
            self.insert(value) // No more mistakes
        }
    }
}
```

In Swift `Index` is defined as follows:

```
public typealias Index = SetIndex<Element>
```

So you could write extension like this:

```
extension Set {
    mutating func addExcludingCurrent(value: Element, currIndex: Index) {
        if value == currIndex {
            return
        } else {
            self.insert(value) // No more mistakes
        }
    }
}
```